# laravel admin able to set username and password for user

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin

i want to ask
is it possible for admin to set up username and password for the employees without the employees need to register their username and password?
if it is possible, how should i do that?

p/s: i'm sorry. i'm new to Laravel

Comment: It is possible and takes some time if you are new in laravel

Comment: i see.. hurm do you mind to tell me how to do that?

Comment: Create form with username email password etc and then define routes and then make controller where you need to add logic to add user to database.